# bxSlider free slide on touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am using the bxslider in my responsive design. When I use the touch/swipe by my phone the slider slides correctly to the next two slides. This happens as well when you slide a bit too far.

I am wondering if it is possible to disable this function and to be able to slide free as you position the slides by yourself or a way to slide quickly to the last slide?

Comment: Have you tried the `oneToOneTouch: true` option? It actually should be true by default.